# How to create UIImage from first page of doc/docx file?

Tags: ios, uiimage, docx, doc

In my app i'm using QLPreviewController to view/read some documents, after tapping it in UICollectionView. Cell in collectionView have an UIImageView and i want to display first page of documents in it like image.

How can i make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the canonical way:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect);
[qlController.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

You can define `rect` to choose the area of the view to convert into an image.